# is there a way to use multiple strings in the jquery :contains() selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i was wondering if there is a way to use multiple strings in the [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/) selector `:contains()`. for example I would liek to do something like this:

```
 $("#"+idArray[i]).find("th:Contains(" + query && query2 + ")").closest($(".instTable, .break")).show();
```

similar to an if statement's sysntax. is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, as you want an `and` condition, that's just the same as filtering for both matches independently.

```
$(selector).find('th:contains(' + query1 +'):contains(' + query2 + ')') ...
```

Comment: @arrowill12 `or` is the same as a set union, so you could use two separate expressions and then use `.add` to merge them.

Comment: how would the syntax look for using `not:` with multiple contains ex.

`:not(:Contains(" + query[x] + "))`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('th:contains('+ query +'), th:contains('+ query2 +')')....
```